# How to find all the records that cause loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query that assign level code to each item in the while loop. I have the table that have data problem need to be clean up. some of the records in the table looks like following:

```
 Product          Ingredient
   XX                 YY
   YY                 XX

   YY                 ZZ
   ZZ                 XX
```

How should I use query to find all the pair that could cause loop. Thanks.

As @JuanCarlosOropeza mentioned. there may be XX-> YY -> ZZ -> XX happened as well.

Comment: is only one level depth of  recursive ingredients? or can `XX-> YY -> ZZ -> XX` happen ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza actually XX-> YY -> ZZ -> XX may happen as well, thanks.

Comment: Can you update your sample to include that case and some more like `AA -> BB --> AA`?  **And also include what is your desire output?**

Comment: You probably can't  have both  `YY->XX`  and `YY -> ZZ` ?

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Try put a litle more effor explaining your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a *Recursive* Common Table Expression or CTE. This should get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx.

I will try to post a code example later in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple

```
 select * from product p1
 inner join product p2 on p1.prod = p2.ingredient 
 inner join p3 on p3.prod = p2.prod and p1.ingredient = p3. Ingredient
```

This matches the recursive products (typed on phone)